# Javascript/jQuery How to get the value of a scale from a matrix value

Tags: javascript, jquery, matrix, scale

A matrix is acquired first.

```
this.getMatrix = function(obj)
{
    var matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
                 obj.css("-moz-transform")    ||
                 obj.css("-ms-transform")     ||
                 obj.css("-o-transform")      ||
                 obj.css("transform");
    return matrix;
};
```

And the value of a scale is acquired.

```
this.getScaleDegrees = function(obj)
{
    var matrix = this.getMatrix(obj),
        matrixRegex = /matrix\((-?\d*\.?\d+),\s*0,\s*0,\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+),\s*0,\s*0\)/,
        matches = matrix.match(matrixRegex);
    return matches;
};
```

And the value of a rotate is acquired.

```
this.getRotationDegrees = function(obj)
{
    var matrix = this.getMatrix(obj),
        angle = 0;

    if(matrix !== 'none') {
        var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(','),
            a = values[0],
            b = values[1];
        angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));
    }

    return angle;
};
```

Now, I am faced with a problem.
The function 'getScaleDegrees' failed, when there are both of rotations and scales of an element.
Since the function 'getRotationDegrees' operates normally,
I think that I will edit the function 'getScaleDegrees' with the help of process of the function 'getRotationDegrees'.

So, question is how to get the value of a scale.

Any good ideas or calculation methods?

---

EDIT:

There is a function to change a scale and rotation and the value of a scale and rotation is different each time. The value which the function 'getMatrix' returns becomes such this.

```
none [no rotate & no scale]  
matrix(1.2, 0, 0, 1.2, 0, 0) [edit scale]  
matrix(0.965926, -0.258819, 0.258819, 0.965926, 0, 0) [edit rotate]  
matrix(1.3523, -0.362347, 0.362347, 1.3523, 0, 0) [edit rotate & edit scale]
```

Comment: What does `matrix` contain?

Comment: There is a function to change a scale and rotation and the value of a scale and rotation is different each time. 
The value which the function 'getMatrix' returns becomes such this. 
`none [no rotate & no scale]` 
`matrix(1.2, 0, 0, 1.2, 0, 0) [edit scale]` 
`matrix(0.965926, -0.258819, 0.258819, 0.965926, 0, 0) [edit rotate]` 
`matrix(1.3523, -0.362347, 0.362347, 1.3523, 0, 0) [edit rotate & edit scale]`

Comment: may be it easer to convert matrix to array ?

Comment: `.replace(/^matrix(3d)?\((.*)\)$/,'$2').split(/, /);`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It returned these values. 
`["1.7","0","0","1.7","0","0"] (scale 1.7)`
 `["1.64207","0.439992","-0.439992","1.64207","0","0"] (scale 1.7 & rotate -15)` `["1.20208","1.20208","-1.20208","1.20208","0","0"] (scale 1.7 & rotate 45)` It seems that it does not work well for my demand.

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution was made.

convert matrix to array (thanx eicto)

```
this.parseMatrix = function(_str)
{
    return _str.replace(/^matrix(3d)?\((.*)\)$/,'$2').split(/, /);
};
```

get the value of a scale

```
this.getScaleDegrees = function(obj)
{
    var matrix = this.parseMatrix(this.getMatrix(obj)),
        scale = 1;

    if(matrix[0] !== 'none') {
        var a = matrix[0],
            b = matrix[1],
            d = 10;
        scale = Math.round( Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b ) * d ) / d;
    }

    return scale;
};
```

'`Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b )`' referred to [CSS-TRICKS](http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/).

Comment: why is d hardcoded to 10?